# Show operator norm attains value under Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I've been trying to show that for $A \in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, there is some $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with $||x|| = 1$ such that $||Ax|| = ||A||$, the operator norm of $A$.

The definition of operator norm used is: $||A|| = sup\{||Ax|| : ||x|| = 1\}$

I've tried proving this by contradiction by constructing a sequence of non-decreasing norms that converges, but I was not able to generate a contradiction.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Any continuous real valued  function on a compact space attains its maximum.

Comment: The comment of @KaviRamaMurthy is the simplest way of seeing this, +1

Comment: I see! It's not immediately obvious to me that this set is compact, though. Compactness in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is equivalent to closedness and boundedness, but knowing this set was closed would solve the original problem... How did you know it is compact?

Comment: We are talking about the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|x\|=1\}$. Is it bounded? yes, of course, all elements have norm one. Is it closed? yes, of course, because the norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and our set is the pre-image of $\{1\}$ which is closed. Continuous functions yield closed sets as pre-images of closed sets (or take $x_n\to x$ with $\|x_n\|=1$ for all $n$. Obviously then $\|x\|=1$ and you are done)

Comment: @JustDroppedIn thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting the required $x$ is to note that $$\|Ax\|^2=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle = x^TA^TAx$$ So one needs to maximize this expression subject to the condition $\|x\|=1$. Since $A^TA$ is symmetric, it follows that any such $x$ is an eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$.

Comment: You are assuming the euclidean norm, and this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP also assumed that.